# AutoCompleteBox does not render correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpftoolkit, ribbon-control

I have an autoCompleteBox in my wpf window and I set ValidatesOnDataErrors binding property to True for selectedItem property of autoCompleteBox control. 
When I show my wpf window by clicking on a  ribbon Button, Validation Area of autocompletbox does not render correctly.

like the picture below:

[image: a correct Item Selected but autocomplete still showing the validation]

but when I show window by clicking on a standard Wpf button it work correctly
like the picture below:

[image: everything are ok]

for more info I create and attached a sample source code:

[sample of my problem](http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1392794761)

can anyone help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you figure out why are there differences in rendering the Window between clicking on a normal Button vs Ribbon button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing both the custom error UI defined in the `AutoCompleteBox`'s control template **and** the standard error template in the adorner. You should disable the latter:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type sysctrls:AutoCompleteBox}">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}" />
</Style>
```